# Finding a route in maze matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, matrix, pathfinding

> **Maze puzzle**
>
> A 1 in input matrix means "allowed"; 0 means "blocked". Given such a matrix, find the route from the 1st quadrant to the last (n-1, n-1).

I would like to get some feedback to optimize and make this code cleaner. Also let me know if O(n!) is the complexity, where n is the dimension of the maze.

```
final class Coordinate {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

public class Maze {

    private final int[][] maze;

    public Maze(int[][] maze) {
        if (maze == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input maze cannot be null");
        }
        if (maze.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The size of maze should be greater than 0");
        }

        this.maze = maze;
    }

    public List<Coordinate> solve() {
        return getMazePath(0, 0, new Stack<Coordinate>());
    }

    private List<Coordinate> getMazePath(int row, int col, Stack<Coordinate> stack) {
        assert stack != null;

        stack.add(new Coordinate(row, col));

        if ((row == maze.length - 1) && (col == maze[0].length - 1)) {
            Coordinate[] coordinateArray = stack.toArray(new Coordinate[stack.size()]);
            return Arrays.asList(coordinateArray);
        }

        for (int j = col; j < maze[row].length; j++) {

            if ((j + 1) < maze[row].length && maze[row][j + 1] == 1) {
                return getMazePath(row, j + 1, stack);
            }

            if ((row + 1) < maze.length && maze[row + 1][col] == 1) {
                return getMazePath(row + 1, col, stack);
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] m = {  {1, 0, 0},
                       {1, 1, 0},
                       {0, 1, 1} };

        Maze maze = new Maze(m);

        for (Coordinate coord :  maze.solve()) {
            System.out.println(coord.getX() + " : " + coord.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't think the time complexity is `O(n!)`. You are doing DFS(unknowingly). So the time complexity would be [O(n + m)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118580/time-complexity) and AFAIK you can't solve maze problem less than that unless you are using BFS. But nevertheless it will not make any difference.

Now your code has some bug, I think you didn't consider that way and it's ok if you are a beginner like me. Try to change the maze matrix to

```
int[][] m = {{1, 1, 1},
             {1, 0, 1},
             {1, 1, 0},                       
             {0, 1, 1}};
```

and you will get the [picture](http://ideone.com/cwlZI6). Maze can be solved but still it's not printing anything.
So what is the solution? **BACK-TRACK**.

Moreover you are only taking account of possibilities of going *right* and *down*, why not *up* and *left*?

You have hard-coded that the start point will be always (0,0) and end point will be (N-1, N-1)... yeah your puzzle says that but this will not be same for every puzzle right? So think of a general solving technique...

**SPOILER ALERT**

> [Web resource](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/)
>
>  [My solution](http://pastebin.com/SNeQB8JN)

### Code Cleaning Tips

1. `getMazePath` method can be cleaned. In 1st `if` you are checking if you have reached the goal or not. Now move the checking condition to another method and return `true` if you have reached the goal.
2. In for loop(no need of this if you are using recursion) you are checking if *you are in the maze* and *path exists or not*... see how you are repeating yourself for every condition... think of a general solution.
3. No need for maintaining a `Stack`, since you are not using any of Stack's method but only `add`, which you can also use with a `List`.
4. Override `toString` method in `Coordinate` class. And get rid of long `S.o.p` s.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is just not correct, with the for-loop.  Consider the following maze:

```
1000001
0000001
0000001
0000001
```

Your code will find a "solution" by jumping to the upper-right, then taking a path down to the finish.

Fix that, and the issues raised by @tintinmj, and then we might be able to analyze the complexity.  Until then, it would be a meaningless discussion.